# Email Already exist or not in Insert/Update using Annotation builder ZF2?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

My TestEntity.php File Consists:

```
/**
 * @Annotation\Type("Zend\Form\Element\Text")
 * @Annotation\Required({"required":"true" })
 * @Annotation\ErrorMessage("Invalid Email")
 * @Annotation\Filter({"name":"StripTags"})
 * @Annotation\Filter({"name":"StringTrim"})
 * @Annotation\Validator({"name":"EmailAddress"})
 * @Annotation\Attributes({"placeholder":"Email"})
 * @Annotation\Attributes({"id":"email"})
 */

public $email;
```

And In Add Form 
I am using

```
  <?php echo $this->formRow($form->get('email')); ?>
```

I want to check at registration time if user filled email id which already exists in database or not, if no then give error if yes then success.

Same condition check while update user profile email id already exist or not but user can fill his original email id means which is user registered.

When I add record_exists  validator it returns error like this:

```
 Zend\Validator\ValidatorPluginManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for record_exists
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: May be "RecordExists" instead of "record_exists"?

Comment: Same Error: Zend\Validator\ValidatorPluginManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for RecordExists

Comment: I think its because `RecordExists` validator placed inside `Db` namespace. You also may try to specify full namespace `Zend\Validator\Db\RecordExists` instead only name.

Comment: I used this:* @Annotation\Validator({"name":"Zend\Validator\Db\RecordExists", "options":{"table":"users","field":"email","adapter":"\Zend\Db\TableGateway\Feature\GlobalAdapterFeature::getStaticAdapter()"}}) but o/p:Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Zend\Validator\Db\AbstractDb::setAdapter() must be an instance of Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter, string given, called in E:\wamp\www\ehr\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Validator\AbstractValidator.php on line 139 and defined in E:\wamp\www\ehr\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Validator\Db\AbstractDb.php on line 168

Comment: I use * @Annotation\Validator({"name":"Zend\Validator\Db\RecordExists", "options":{"table":"users","field":"email","adapter":"\Zend\Db\TableGateway\Feature\GlobalAdapterFeature::getStaticAdapter()"}})

Comment: Update your answer with this code, he is not readable in comment

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44225/discussion-between-microbe-and-chirag)

Answer (score 0):

I found it [here](http://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2012/08/28/set-default-db-adapter-in-zend-framework-2/) among comments.

If you implement adapter in service factory configuration by some callback, before return adapter you must register it in static registry.

For example, inside global configuration file `config/autoload/global.php`:

```
<?php

return aray(
    'db' => array(
        <Driver, dsn etc here>
    ),
    'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter' => function($sm){
                $adapterFactory = new Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory();
                $adapter = $adapterFactory->createService($sm);
                \Zend\Db\TableGateway\Feature\GlobalAdapterFeature::setStaticAdapter($adapter);
                return $adapter;
            }
        ),
    ),
);
```

After that database adapter available by:

```
\Zend\Db\TableGateway\Feat‌​ure\GlobalAdapterFeature::getStaticAdapter()
```

Comment: Hi Microbe its returns same error : Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Zend\Validator\Db\AbstractDb::setAdapter() must be an instance of Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter, string given, called in E:\wamp\www\ehr\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Validator\AbstractValidator.php on line 139 and defined in E:\wamp\www\ehr\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Validator\Db\AbstractDb.php on line 168

Comment: Ok. Can you show what is this string? Are you using some debugging tool?

Comment: No I dont use any debugging tool.How to use this tool?which tool use?

Comment: First, you must choose some IDE (I use JetBrains PhpStorm, but he is not free. Other opensource alternative is Netbeans). After that you must install 'xdebug' php extension and properly tune it. There are lot of videos in internet about how to tune your IDE for using xebug.

Comment: Skip this question i have found another solutions.